# Mysql: insert multiple values with order number

Tags: mysql, string, split, insert

I want to split a string like ('abc', 'dev', dfg') and insert into a table with its order number like that:

```
index    value
    1     abc
    2     dev
    3     dfg
```

Is anyway I can do this in mysql? The size is unknown.

Comment: You need to post how the original data look like. And depending on your MySQL version, there are different type of operation you can do, so please run `SELECT version();` to check your MySQL version as well.

Comment: Thanks @FanoFn. It is 8.0.11. I have a stored procedure and will pass an array of uuid strings using the comma to separate them. Need to put those Ids in a table with the order number in the string. Or I can change the parameter to different format like json object {1: "abc", 2: "dev", 3: "dfg" , ... }, will it be easier?

Comment: Let's work with what you have. Having it to convert to json will probably be more confusing and require more steps to pivot than plain string separated by comma. I assume there's a single column with `'abc', 'dev', dfg'` as the example sting value, is it? I'm also guessing that you don't actually have the `index` value (in your expected result) stored in the table. It's something that you want to generate based on the (separated by comma) string position, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can do something like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
SELECT 1 idx, LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(stringVal,'[^,]',''))+1 AS maxLen 
  FROM mytable UNION
SELECT idx+1, maxLen FROM cte WHERE idx+1 <= maxLen)

SELECT idx,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(stringVal,',',idx),',',-1) AS val
  FROM cte
CROSS JOIN mytable;
```

Generating `idx` using `cte` based on how many strings were separated by comma in the column. The steps are:

1. Use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` to replace any value that is not comma; returns `,,`.
2. Use `LENGTH()` on the regexp to get the total of comma; returns `2`.
3. Add 1 (+1) to the length result returned; final value `3`.
4. The `cte` result are:

```
    +-----+--------+
    | idx | maxLen |
    +-----+--------+
    |  1  |   3    |
    |  2  |   3    |
    |  3  |   3    |
    +-----+--------+
```

From the generated `cte` , we're going to use `idx` value with `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to separate the comma-separated, single-row string into multiple rows.

Understanding what the query is doing:
This, we can emulate with 3 of the same query repeated `UNION ALL` together like the following:

```
SELECT 1 AS 'index',
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(stringVal,',',1),',',-1) AS val
  FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(stringVal,',',2),',',-1)
  FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(stringVal,',',3),',',-1)
  FROM mytable;
```

Which also can be done as such; Same idea as the `cte` approach:

```
SELECT idx,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(stringVal,',',idx),',',-1) AS val
  FROM (SELECT 1 idx UNION
        SELECT 2 UNION
        SELECT 3 ) i
CROSS JOIN mytable;
```

Both of these query return the same result as the `cte` approach however it's not an ideal one; since we have to manually check how many string separated by comma and define (hard-code) it in the query. Imagine if a single row of string consists of something like `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z` - all the 26 alphabet; then that means the `UNION` query need to be repeated 26 times.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ae2f0dc88f40a7235657da43138dd173)